# Error in browser: The application unexpectedly exited. Diagnostic information has been dumped to JavaScript error console while using shiny-server

Tags: r, html, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to deploy a shiny web app on shiny-server. But everytime it gives the error :
"The application unexpectedly exited. Diagnostic information has been dumped to JavaScript error console"
The error shown in the error console is as follows:
"Listening on http://127.0.0.1:58865
Error in library(htmlwidgets) : there is no package called ‘htmlwidgets’".

I have installed the package 'htmlwidgets' on my machine. Still it always shows the error. the application works file in Rstudio but it is giving this error on browser when I run it on Shiny-server. Please suggest a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/#run_as In particular, please note this:

> For one, the paths in which R will look for packages (`.libPaths()`) are often user-dependent.

One way to solve the problem is, just like how you installed **shiny**, you may also install **htmlwidgets** to *system-wide* library paths, e.g.

```
sudo su - \
  -c "R -e \"install.packages('htmlwidgets', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

Comment: I am using the pc as administrator and I have granted read write access to all users and I've also shared the directory over the network. I'm trying to run it on shiny server as localhost but still it is showing the same error.

I'm not deploying my app on ShinyApps.io, I'm I'm only using it on Shiny-Server over LAN. Still to make sure I've mentioned library(htmlwidgets) in the source code but it doesn't help.

Please suggest solution. Thanks.

Comment: Installing package to system-wide library along with run_as command in .conf file worked. Thanks a lot!